# is it possible to run a completable future in the same thread in which it is created?

Tags: java, java-8, completable-future

Would like to know if a completablefuture can be run in the thread in which it was created. You might ask why would I need to do so since completablefuture is for async programming. The reason is that I have few async tasks and some tasks that I want to run in the spawning thread so that I can use allOf etc and maintain consistency in the code

Comment: Perhaps you should consider do those tasks that need to run in the same thread using a different API, like the stream API and leave to the completable future only those that you truly need to run asynchronously. My point being that perhaps there's something wrong in your design if you indeed need to something like this.

Answer (score 5):

When you say you want to know whether "a completablefuture can be run in the thread in which it was created", you are exhibiting a wrong mindset. A `CompletableFuture` doesn't run. A `CompletableFuture` just encapsulates a value or exception, which can be set at most one time, which we call *completing* it.

The API offers a lot of methods for scheduling completion attempts, potentially asynchronous, but you shouldn't get distracted from the fact that you decide how to complete it.

There are simple alternatives to asynchronous completion:

```
CompletableFuture<String> f = CompletableFuture.completedFuture("hello");
```

creates an immediately completed future. Java 9 adds `failedFuture` to support creating an immediately exceptionally completed future.

You can also easily create a future to be completed at a later time within the same thread:

```
CompletableFuture<String> f = new CompletableFuture<>();

// arbitrary actions

f.complete("hello");
```

You can also use the factory methods with an executor, immediately running the action in the initiating thread:

```
CompletableFuture<String> f
  = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> "hello", Runnable::run);
```

or

```
CompletableFuture<String> f
  = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    if(Math.random() > 0.5) throw new IllegalStateException();
    return "hello";
  }, Runnable::run);
```

to demonstrate the difference to an invocation of `complete` or creating an immediately completed future.

Of course, these possibilities can be combined with the other features, like `allOf`:

```
CompletableFuture<String> a = new CompletableFuture<>();
CompletableFuture<String> b = new CompletableFuture<>();
CompletableFuture<String> c = new CompletableFuture<>();

CompletableFuture.allOf(a, b, c).whenComplete((__, t) -> {
  if(t != null) System.err.println("failed with "+t);
  else System.out.println("all completed "+a.join()+", "+b.join()+", "+c.join());
});

System.out.println("step 1");
a.complete("foo");
System.out.println("step 2");
b.complete("bar");
System.out.println("step 3");
c.complete("baz");
```

Comment: When I say 'CompletableFuture', I am alluding to the feature as a whole and not the meaning of the class itself. I like your completedFuture() answer and this means that what I asked is very much relevant since java has already provided it.

Comment: Though it doesn't help fully as it is just returning a result and not doing any task. Can I execute a task within it??

Comment: In this case "the feature as a whole" is distracting from how it works. Understanding, how it works helps understanding things like why it is impossible to interrupt a task with `cancel` (the future doesn't represent the action) or why canceling the future of a chain of actions only cancels the last action (the future only represents the last result, not the chain). I don't know what you mean with "not doing any task". In the second example "`// arbitrary actions`" can be any task, in the third and forth, a `Supplier` (a task) is executed, in the 5th, `whenComplete` schedules a task...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, perfectly possible. Here is a sample program which demonstrates

```
private static ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    executor.execute(() -> {
        System.out.println("Scheduling " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            System.out.println("Sleeping " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {}

            System.out.println("Returning " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            return 123;
        },
        executor)
        .thenAccept(retValue -> System.out.println("Got value " + retValue + " " + Thread.currentThread().getName()));
    });
}
```

Output

```
Scheduling pool-1-thread-1
Sleeping pool-1-thread-1
Returning pool-1-thread-1
Got value 123 pool-1-thread-1
```

Comment: The only problem is that this run all operations in the same thread of the executor and the OP suggests that s/he wants to run a few steps in a different thread. If this was the case, then what's the point of using a completable future?

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo It would be a mistake to conflate concurrency with parallelism.